# flutter custom annotation like Required

Tags: flutter, dart

what I want is an annotation like `@required` but I want to do some logic based on the type of parameter and show the use a warning like what `@required` does.
(if type is `ParamTuple` shows the warning)

```
abstract class Tuple {
  const Tuple();
}

abstract class NullTuple extends Tuple {
  const NullTuple();
}

abstract class ParamTuple extends Tuple {
  const ParamTuple();
}
```

I want to warn user if the type is ParamTuple but in other cases I don't want warning.

**In the code below, the logic should be implemented**

```
const TupleRequired tupleRequired = TupleRequired();

class TupleRequired {
  const TupleRequired();
}
```

also I think that I should add an `analysis_options.yaml` to show warning like `@required` for my `@tupleRequired`.

**EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT**

```
class Example {
  // Tuple0 extends NullTuple 
  void nullParam({@tupleRequired Tuple0 param}) {}

  // Tuple1 extends ParamTuple  
  void withParam({@tupleRequired Tuple1 param}) {}
}
```

so when we want to use these methods, I want to see the below custom warning:

1. `nullParam` : if I put it empty , shows nothing but if I pass an argument shows the argument is redundant and will be ignored
2. `withParam` : if I put it empty , shows warning to pass argument and if I pass an argument shows nothing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Can you give an example of code you want and of the message you would like to receive?

Comment: I added an example, hope it helped and clarify what I want,

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor You can use assert like:

```
class TupleRequired {
  final Tuple touple;
  TupleRequired(this.touple): assert(touple is! ParamTuple);

}
```

in dart is/is! checks if an object is of specific type like for example

```
var s = 'this is a string type';
print(s is String); // prints true because s is string
print(s is! int); // prints true because s is not an int
```